# Is there any specific case study to follow when developing a postcode system?

Tags: postcode

I'm developing a postcode system to a country that doesnt exist one (in fact we have one to reflect a main post office with a really large area to cover -less granularity- hence no one really uses it). 
I would like to know if there is any project case I can follow something similar to this?

I'm not a developer or programmer but has a team to carry out the work. We are still in the very early stage of the process.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a granulated (detailed) postal code system, you will first need to create a detailed database with (preferably) official addresses.   You cannot assign a postal code to an address that is not in a database.

Notice that 'official addresses' is not the same as 'legally licenced constructions'.  The first is normally within the domain of the Ministry of Interior (e.g. for police or tax matters), while the second is usually within the competence of the Ministry of Urban Planning !  Although the most efficient way is to combine these two elements into one single database for practical reasons.

So probably, you will first have to create a website allowing local authorities to insert all local addresses into one single national database. This needs to be done locally because of the massive workload.  After validation (meaning : official verification and proclamation), that address database can then very easily be used for assigning postal codes.

I have built such website as a consultant other countries and it is a very speedy way of proceeding with this type a projects.  The final structure of your database will depend of course entirely on your country's adminitrative (sub)divisions.  Such a system will allow you  to create a single postal code for each distinct street (with the possibility of further detailing up to the level of the indiviual house-number itself, even apartment number).

As for the postal codes themselves to become internationally effective, you will need to follow UPU procedures.  There are a number of steps and requirements to fulfill.  But that only relates to the handling of international post to your country, coming from any other given country. Anyway, that is only a legal/administrative process that as no bearing on your project code.

Comment: Appreciate your feedback and thank you very much. The project is currently not overlooked by the authorities since this is basically a project we've started to provide an efficient route planning system etc. Can we approach  UPU -do they consider- to sign us in as a private institution, cos the existing system is already registered with the UPU as the government. Our aim is to start with the public to record data in a similar website. Do you have any suggestions as to what data must be collected please. Thanks in advance.